I am getting this error when compiling gradle project how can I solve it
import in.novopay.infra.platform.core.ThreadLocalContext;
^
bad class file: C:\Users\Sourav.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\in.novopay\infra-platform\1.0.5.RELEASE\5771c6ef6ce862090a3659b2829ba3abc860dd36\infra-platform-1.0.5.RELEASE.jar(in/novopay/infra/platform/core/ThreadLocalContext.class)
class file has wrong version 55.0, should be 52.0
Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.


Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

it should build completely but its not building and giving above error.

you are somewhere using a library that is compiled with a newer version of the java compiler compared to the one  you are using

how can i find this library or the compile version.

@Sourav see here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se21/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.1-200-B.2 for class file version vs java version

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

It seems that the class file "ThreadLocalContext.class" has been compiled with Java 11 (version 55.0), but your project is trying to compile it with Java 8 (version 52.0), which is causing the compilation failure.
